# Scroll bar needed in WPF sound visualizer control at codeplex

Tags: wpf

I am using  WPF sound visualizer control at codeplex ( http://wpfsvl.codeplex.com/).
Whenever an audio file is loaded, the audio is loaded into waveform timeline control with fixed length. So when any length audio is loaded, it adjusts to waveform timeline control width. I am unable to add a scrollbar to the waveform timeline control so that based on the length of audio, the waveform timeline control width enlarges.

i referenced the dll in my solution and included the below in my xaml file

```
xmlns:svl="clr-namespace:WPFSoundVisualizationLib;assembly=WPFSoundVisualizationLib"
```

And i added waveform timeline  control in xaml

```
<svl:WaveformTimeline x:Name="waveformTimeline"/>
```

To load an audio file into this control, the following code is used in xaml.cs

```
NAudioEngine.Instance.OpenFile("audio file");
NAudioEngine soundEngine = NAudioEngine.Instance;
soundEngine.PropertyChanged += NAudioEngine_PropertyChanged;
UIHelper.Bind(soundEngine, "CanStop", StopButton, Button.IsEnabledProperty);
UIHelper.Bind(soundEngine, "CanPlay", PlayButton, Button.IsEnabledProperty);
UIHelper.Bind(soundEngine, "CanPause", PauseButton, Button.IsEnabledProperty);
UIHelper.Bind(soundEngine, "CanSave", PauseButton, Button.IsEnabledProperty);
waveformTimeline.RegisterSoundPlayer(soundEngine);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used 2 controls to solve the zoom in/zoom out problem. The controls are ScrollViewer and Slider.

First i embedded WaveformTimeline control into the ScrollViewer control like below

```
<ScrollViewer  x:Name="waveScroll"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="0,99,10,-95">
     <svl:WaveformTimeline x:Name="waveformTimeline"
         Margin="5" Width="8000"
         BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" >
         <svl:WaveformTimeline.LayoutTransform>
              <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=xscroll, Path=Value}" />
         </svl:WaveformTimeline.LayoutTransform>
     </svl:WaveformTimeline>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And i added Slider control and bind that control here in WaveformTimeline control .

```
<Slider Name="xscroll" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Minimum=".5" 
Maximum="2.0" Ticks=".5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.75" 
IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Value="1" SmallChange=".25" LargeChange=".25" 
Margin="84,201,248,-122" />
```

When i move the slider, it zooms in/zooms out based on the direction of movement.